# Android GUI: Y Axis Inversion

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, screen

Somehow the Y-axis of my Android display became inverted. I'm looking for a way to return it to normal. At this stage I don't care if it's a real solution to the original problem or a workaround.

Only the visual display is inverted, not the touch sensor; the two are out of phase with each other. In other words, the home button that usually lives at the bottom of the screen, appears up the top, but the trigger is still down the bottom. It's.. frustrating.

Yes, I've tried a factory reset.
No, rotation isn't a solution. I made this to demonstrate the difference:

[image]

---

I read somewhere that I need to change `ro.sf.hwrotation=180` to `ro.sf.hwrotation=0` in `/system/build.prop`, but that line isn't present on my device; an old LG Nexus 5 (Hammerhead). I'm hoping SurfaceFlinger might have some kind of config file somewhere that I can edit or something like that. Any ideas?